# window.location inside js function called by onclick

Tags: javascript

**I have an html file-**

```
<a href="#abc" onclick="return somefunc()">Click</a>
```

**Js file-**

```
function somefunc() {
    if(somecondition) {
    //do domething
    }
    else {
         window.location='#xyz';
         return false;
    }
```

If else condition is triggered, it takes me to `#xyz` and then again back to `#abc`. I want to redirect to `#xyz` when else part occurs.

Comment: i tried that too. not working.

Comment: remove that `return false;` and try again. if might be the reason.

Comment: @Patriks `return false` must stay in if this should have any hope of working, as it prevents the default action of the link in favor of the client-side redirection. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: why don't you replace `href="#abc"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"`. and add this `window.location.href = '#abc';` to that javascript function inside if.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript error in the console after you click the link?

Comment: @PointedEars you should accept suggestions from all, as all are not aware about your exact situation, you didn't write that you are more concern about search engines too. every one is trying to help you here. People are not here to waste their time. all are helping you.

Comment: Nope, not getting error in the console. It first takes me to #xyz and then back to #abc.

Comment: @Patriks At SO we are looking for *informed* answers. Blind leading the blind can only make matters *worse*. BTW, I am not asking for help in this question.

Comment: @PrashantBaid In that case you should post the entire code of `somefunc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not let it return false as that will cancel the default action. You probably want to include a return false in your 'do something' area though.

Comment: Need to return false to cancel default action, he want to go to #xyz instead of abc

Comment: The default action would be to go to `#abc` which he *doesn't* want. Actually, that's probably the problem.

Comment: I don't want default action when I am inside the else part. I want to redirect to #xyz and not #abc inside the else part.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working fine for me like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
<a href="#abc" onclick="return somefunc()">Click</a>

<div class="filler"></div>
<div id="abc">ABC location</div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div id="xyz">XYZ location</div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function somefunc () {

    var returnState = true;
    if (document.getElementById("cb").checked) {
         alert("here");   
    } else {
        window.location.hash = "#xyz";
        returnState = false;                
    }
    return returnState;

}​
```

**Running Example**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHxJ5/)